# future element doesn't get binded with on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(".closeBtn").on('click',function(){
        alert('');
    });

+function myfunction(){

    $(".elem").on('click',function(){
        $("#someId").html('<img class="closeBtn" src=""/>'
        );
    });

}();
```

I used html to add some element into somewhere, I checked my dom and things are there. When I click the binded element closeBtn, it doesn't have respond. I thought using on() will work? or it's closure problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
 $("body").on('click','.closeBtn',function(){
   alert('test');
 });
```

**[Check Syntax For event delegation using on](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**